# MongoDB Replication addition failing

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to add 2 slaves in mongodb replication after successful initialization. But unfortunately it is failing.

repset_init.js file details

```
rs.add( { host: "10.0.1.170:27017" } )
rs.add( { host: "10.0.2.157:27017" } )
rs.add( { host: "10.0.3.88:27017" } )
```

command which i have executed for replicaset addition

```
mongo -u xxxxx -p yyyy  --authenticationDatabase admin --port 27017 repset_init.js
```

command hangs in terminal and below is the log output

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-09T12:29:34.939+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21393,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Found self in config","attr":{"hostAndPort":"MongoD-1:27017"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-09T12:29:34.939+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"local.system.replset","appName":"MongoDB Shell","command":{"replSetReconfig":{"_id":"Shard_0","version":2,"protocolVersion":1,"writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault":true,"members":[{"_id":0,"host":"MongoD-1:27017","arbiterOnly":false,"buildIndexes":true,"hidden":false,"priority":1.0,"tags":{},"slaveDelay":0,"votes":1},{"host":"10.0.2.157:27017","_id":1.0}],"settings":{"chainingAllowed":true,"heartbeatIntervalMillis":2000,"heartbeatTimeoutSecs":10,"electionTimeoutMillis":10000,"catchUpTimeoutMillis":-1,"catchUpTakeoverDelayMillis":30000,"getLastErrorModes":{},"getLastErrorDefaults":{"w":1,"wtimeout":0},"replicaSetId":{"$oid":"60c0b3566991d93637465f55"}}},"lsid":{"id":{"$uuid":"263568b4-ec31-4ea6-8f72-69cec80c1a7c"}},"$db":"admin"},"numYields":0,"reslen":38,"locks":{"ParallelBatchWriterMode":{"acquireCount":{"r":3}},"ReplicationStateTransition":{"acquireCount":{"w":5}},"Global":{"acquireCount":{"r":1,"w":4}},"Database":{"acquireCount":{"w":2,"W":1}},"Collection":{"acquireCount":{"w":2}},"Mutex":{"acquireCount":{"r":2}}},"flowControl":{"acquireCount":2,"timeAcquiringMicros":3},"storage":{},"protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":151}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-09T12:29:34.940+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21215,   "ctx":"ReplCoord-1","msg":"Member is in new state","attr":{"hostAndPort":"10.0.2.157:27017","newState":"STARTUP"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-09T12:29:34.941+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4508702, "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Waiting for the current config to propagate to a majority of nodes"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-09T12:33:55.701+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20712,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheReap","msg":"Sessions collection is not set up; waiting until next sessions reap interval","attr":{"error":"ShardingStateNotInitialized: sharding state is not yet initialized"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-09T12:33:55.701+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20714,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheRefresh","msg":"Failed to refresh session cache, will try again at the next refresh interval","attr":{"error":"ShardingStateNotInitialized: sharding state is not yet initialized"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-09T12:34:35.029+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONNPOOL", "id":22572,   "ctx":"MirrorMaestro","msg":"Dropping all pooled connections","attr":{"hostAndPort":"10.0.2.157:27017","error":"ShutdownInProgress: Pool for 10.0.2.157:27017 has expired."}}
```

Additional details:

```
Shard_0:PRIMARY> rs.printSlaveReplicationInfo() 
WARNING: printSlaveReplicationInfo is deprecated and may be removed in the next major release. Please use printSecondaryReplicationInfo instead.
source: 10.0.2.157:27017
syncedTo: Thu Jan 01 1970 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC) 1623243005 secs (450900.83 hrs) behind the primary
```

Able to reach the node via port 27017

```
telnet 10.0.2.157 27017
Trying 10.0.2.157...
Connected to 10.0.2.157.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

My config file

```
net:
 bindIp: 0.0.0.0
 port: 27017
 ssl: {}

processManagement:
 fork: "true"
 pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid

replication:
 replSetName: Shard_0

security:
 authorization: enabled
 keyFile: /etc/zzzzzkey.key

setParameter:
 authenticationMechanisms: SCRAM-SHA-256

sharding:
 clusterRole: shardsvr

storage:
 dbPath: /data/dbdata
 engine: wiredTiger

systemLog:
 destination: file
 path: /data/log/mongodb.log
```

I'm initializing replicaset using below cmd

```
mongo --host 127.0.0.1 --port {{mongod_port}} --eval 'printjson(rs.initiate())'
```

Not sure what causing this issue. Could you please help me

Comment: Did you initialize the replica set? - `rs.initiate()`, see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.initiate/

Comment: Did you setup the MongoDB config server?

Comment: No i didn't setup MongoDB config server yet

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Even config server rs failing and created - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67906545/mongodb-config-server-replication-setup-failing-pinging-failed-for-distributed

Comment: You have to follow this tutorial carefully: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-sharded-cluster-with-keyfile-access-control/

Answer (score 0):

The command looks a bit strange:

```
{
  "replSetReconfig": {
     "_id": "Shard_0",
     "members": [
        { "_id": 0, "host": "MongoD-1:27017", "arbiterOnly": false, "hidden": false, "priority": 1.0, "slaveDelay": 0, "votes": 1 },
        { "_id": 1.0, "host": "10.0.2.157:27017" }
     ],
  }
}
```

Why do you name your replica set `Shard_0`? Do you try to setup a Sharded Cluster?

You add `_id: 0, host: "MongoD-1:27017"` and `_id: 1.0, host: "10.0.2.157:27017"` which is not consistent, i.e. you mixed IP-Address and hostname. Also _id "0" and "1.0" is confusing.

How does your config files look like and how did you start the MongoDB services?

Comment: added config file and initialization cmd.Since initialization automatically fetching hostname instead of ip,we are seeing that host,ip mismatch