# MongoDB Config server replication setup failing - Pinging failed for distributed lock pinger

Tags: mongodb

I have to setup 2 node mongodb config server(for testing) and when adding second node as slave it is failing

repset_init.js file details

```
rs.add( { host: "10.0.1.222:27017" } )
rs.add( { host: "10.0.2.41:27017" } )
printjson(rs.status())
```

command executed for replicaset addition

```
mongo -u xxxxx -p yyyy  --authenticationDatabase admin --port 27017 repset_init.js
```

My initialization command

```
mongo --host 127.0.0.1 --port {{mongod_port}} --eval 'printjson(rs.initiate())'
```

My config file

```
net:
 bindIp: 0.0.0.0
 port: 27017
 ssl: {}

processManagement:
 fork: "true"
 pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid

replication:
 replSetName: configRS

security:
 authorization: enabled
 keyFile: /etc/zzzzzkey.key

setParameter:
 authenticationMechanisms: SCRAM-SHA-256

sharding:
 clusterRole: configsvr

storage:
 dbPath: /data/dbdata
 engine: wiredTiger

systemLog:
 destination: file
 path: /data/log/mongodb.log
```

Below are the errors in the log file

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-09T14:37:36.071+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4508702, "ctx":"conn16","msg":"Waiting for the current config to propagate to a majority of nodes"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-09T14:37:53.143+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"replSetDistLockPinger","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"config.lockpings","command":{"findAndModify":"lockpings","query":{"_id":"ConfigServer"},"update":{"$set":{"ping":{"$date":"2021-06-09T14:37:38.125Z"}}},"upsert":true,"writeConcern":{"w":"majority","wtimeout":15000},"$db":"config"},"planSummary":"IDHACK","keysExamined":1,"docsExamined":1,"nMatched":1,"nModified":1,"keysInserted":1,"keysDeleted":1,"numYields":0,"reslen":585,"locks":{"ParallelBatchWriterMode":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"ReplicationStateTransition":{"acquireCount":{"w":1}},"Global":{"acquireCount":{"w":1}},"Database":{"acquireCount":{"w":1}},"Collection":{"acquireCount":{"w":1}},"Mutex":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}}},"flowControl":{"acquireCount":1,"timeAcquiringMicros":1},"writeConcern":{"w":"majority","wtimeout":15000,"provenance":"clientSupplied"},"storage":{},"protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":15017}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-09T14:37:53.143+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":22668,   "ctx":"replSetDistLockPinger","msg":"Pinging failed for distributed lock pinger","attr":{"error":{"code":64,"codeName":"WriteConcernFailed","errmsg":"waiting for replication timed out; Error details: { wtimeout: true, writeConcern: { w: \"majority\", wtimeout: 15000, provenance: \"clientSupplied\" } }"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-09T14:38:08.065+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONNPOOL", "id":22572,   "ctx":"MirrorMaestro","msg":"Dropping all pooled connections","attr":{"hostAndPort":"10.0.2.41:27017","error":"ShutdownInProgress: Pool for 10.0.2.41:27017 has expired."}}
```

Please guide me

Comment: Users are created **after** you initiated the replica set. Try to run the commands manually rather than from .js script or --eval. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-sharded-cluster-with-keyfile-access-control/

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit i'm doing this via ansible.Thats the reason i'm using file or eval

Comment: I also deploy my sharded cluster with ansible. However, before your automate it, try it manually first. In recent ansible you have already some plugins [Community.Mongodb](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/mongodb/index.html#plugins-in-community-mongodb) - maybe try it out. I never used it, it is still to limited.

Comment: when i try to add rplset using rs.add() i got error - not authorized on local to execute command.Thats the reason i'm creating user and then trying rplset add.Is it possible to add replset without user creation? also instead of rs.add,is it possible to use rs.initiate with config?But if i try that again i'm getting error - not authorized on local to execute command.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit tried using ansible modules but no luck.Created another question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67909444/how-ansible-mongodb-user-mongodb-replicaset-modules-working