# How ansible mongodb_user,mongodb_replicaset modules working?

Tags: mongodb, ansible

I'm trying to automate MongoDB installation along with replication setup via ansible. So as part of that, I want to utilize ansible modules mongodb_user,mongodb_replicaset. When using this module I'm facing some issues. So need some light on this

Issue - 1:
when I create an admin user using mongodb_user I'm getting the below error

```
  - name: Create MongoDB root user admin
    mongodb_user:
        login_port: "{{ mongod_port }}"
        database: "{{ mongodb_db_name }}"
        name: "{{ mongodb_admin_user }}"
        password: "{{ mongodb_admin_password }}"
        roles: "root"
```

Getting error as below

```
 "msg": "Unable to add or update user: not master, full error: {'topologyVersion': {'processId': ObjectId('60c0f9ebe9bf9941528836df'), 'counter': 0}, 'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'not master', 'code': 10107, 'codeName': 'NotWritablePrimary', '$gleStats': {'lastOpTime': Timestamp(0, 0), 'electionId': ObjectId('000000000000000000000000')}, 'lastCommittedOpTime': Timestamp(0, 0)}"
    }
```

From the error, I can understand it will work only after do the MongoDB initialization

so I did that as below

```
- name: Initiate the Replicaset
  command: "mongo --host 127.0.0.1 --port {{mongod_port}} --eval 'printjson(rs.initiate())'"
```

After that I'm able to create user successfully

Now I'm trying to add replica set using below module but unfortunately, it is not added and not thrown any error.No changes happened

```
- name: Ensure replicaset Shard_0 exists
  mongodb_replicaset:
    login_host: localhost
    login_user: xxxxx
    login_password: yyyyy
    replica_set: configRS
    #members: "{{ groups['MongoC'] }}"
    members: "{{ groups['MongoC'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_host']) | join(':27017,') }}:27017"
  when: (groups['MongoC']|sort())[0] == inventory_hostname
```

output:

```
ok: [MongoC-1] => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "arbiter_at_index": null,
            "auth_mechanism": null,
            "chaining_allowed": true,
            "connection_options": null,
            "election_timeout_millis": 10000,
            "heartbeat_timeout_secs": 10,
            "login_database": "admin",
            "login_host": "localhost",
            "login_password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "login_port": 27017,
            "login_user": "xxxxx",
            "members": [
                "10.0.1.141:27017",
                "10.0.2.229:27017",
                "10.0.3.30:27017"
            ],
            "protocol_version": 1,
            "replica_set": "configRS",
            "ssl": false,
            "ssl_ca_certs": null,
            "ssl_cert_reqs": "CERT_REQUIRED",
            "ssl_certfile": null,
            "ssl_crlfile": null,
            "ssl_keyfile": null,
            "ssl_pem_passphrase": null,
            "validate": true
        }
    },
    "replica_set": "configRS"
}
```

Am I using the modules in the right way?

Tried rs.initiate instead of ansible module like below

replicaset.js

```
rs.initiate({
 _id: "configRS",
 configsvr: true,
 members: [
  { _id: 1, host : "10.0.1.73:27017" },
  { _id: 2, host : "10.0.2.144:27017" },
  { _id: 3, host : "10.0.3.18:27017" },
  ]
 }
);
```

command:

```
"mongo --port 27017 replicaset.js"
```

Got the error as below:

```
\t\"errmsg\" : \"not authorized on admin to execute command { replSetGetConfig: 1.0, lsid: { id: UUID(\\\"788e7cff-218c-4605-ab68-b3b6751634ca\\\") }, $db: \\\"admin\\\" }\",",
        "\t\"code\" : 13,",
        "\t\"codeName\" : \"Unauthorized\",",
```

Comment: The root user should be created in admin database, i.e. `database: "admin"` (which is the default). Admin user is created after `rs.initiate`, thus `login_user/login_password` needs to be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `printjson(rs.initiate())` try

```
rs.initiate(
  {
    _id: "configRS",
    configsvr: true,
    members: [
      { _id: 0, host: "10.0.1.141:27017" },
      { _id: 1, host: "10.0.2.229:27017" },
      { _id: 2, host: "10.0.3.30:27017" }
    ]
  }
);
rs.status();
while (! db.isMaster().ismaster ) { sleep(1000) }
```

Then you don't need to add any member.

For CSRS I use a playbook like this:

```
- hosts: config
  tasks:
  - name: Compose variables
    set_fact:
      rs_initiate: |      
        {% set members = [] %}
        {% for host in groups['config']  | sort %}
        {% set m = {'_id': loop.index0 } %}
        {% set _ = m.update({'host': host + '.' + ansible_domain + ':' + ports.config | string }) %}
        {% set _ = members.append(m) %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% set init = {'_id': replica_set.conf} %}
        {% set _ = init.update({'members': members}) %}
        {% set _ = init.update({'configsvr': true}) %}
        {{ init }}
      rs_members: |
        {% set members = [] %}
        {% for host in groups['config'] | sort %}
        {% set _ = members.append(host + '.' + ansible_domain + ':' + ports.config | string) %}
        {% endfor %}
        {{ members }}
      replicaSetURI: "mongodb://{{ groups['config'] | product([ports.config]) | map('join', ':') | join(',') }}/admin?authSource=admin&replicaSet={{ replica_set.conf }}" 

  - name: Check if Config Replicaset is initiated
    shell: 
      cmd: "/usr/bin/mongo --norc --quiet localhost:{{ ports.config }}"
      executable: /bin/bash
      stdin: "rs.status().codeName" 
    register: result
    changed_when: false
    check_mode: no
  
  
  - set_fact:
# Needed to ensure that the Config Server Replica Set (CSRS) is initiated only once
      rs: |
        {% set i = (result.stdout == 'NotYetInitialized') %}
        {% for host in ansible_play_hosts %}
        {% set i = i and (hostvars[host].result.stdout == 'NotYetInitialized') %}
        {% endfor %}
        {{ {'NotYetInitialized': i} }}
  
  
  
  - name: Initiate Config Replicaset
    shell: 
      cmd: "/usr/bin/mongo --norc --quiet localhost:{{ ports.config }}"
      executable: /bin/bash
      stdin: |
        var i = rs.initiate({{ rs_initiate | to_json }})
        if (i.ok != 1) print(i.errmsg)
        var _ = rs.status()
        while (! db.isMaster().ismaster ) sleep(1000)
        rs.status().members.map(x => x.name)
        if (i.ok == 1) {print(rs.status().ok)} else {print(0)}
    register: ret
    failed_when: ret.stdout_lines | last != "1"
    when: rs.NotYetInitialized and inventory_hostname_short == groups['config'] | sort | first)
  
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ ret.stdout_lines }}"
    when: not ansible_check_mode and rs.NotYetInitialized and inventory_hostname_short == (groups['config'] | sort | first) and ret.stdout != ''
```

In order to add hosts to existing CSRS I use this one:

```
- hosts: config
  tasks:
  
  - meta: end_play
    when: ansible_check_mode or rs.NotYetInitialized | default(false)

  - name: Check current Config Server Replica Set members
    shell: 
      cmd: "/usr/bin/mongo -u admin -p {{ password.admin }} --authenticationDatabase admin --norc --quiet localhost:{{ ports.config }}"
      executable: /bin/bash
      stdin: "rs.status().members.map(x => x.name)"
    register: result
    changed_when: false
    when: inventory_hostname_short == (groups['config'] | sort | first)

  - set_fact:
      current_members: "{{ result.stdout | from_json }}"
    when: inventory_hostname_short == (groups['config'] | sort | first)

  - name: Add host to Config Server Replica Set
    shell: 
      cmd: "/usr/bin/mongo -u admin -p {{ password.admin }} --authenticationDatabase admin --norc --quiet localhost:{{ ports.config }}"
      executable: /bin/bash
      stdin: "rs.add('{{ item }}')"
    when: inventory_hostname_short == (groups['config'] | sort | first)
    loop: "{{ rs_members | difference(current_members) | sort }}"
    register: ret
    failed_when: ret.stdout != ""
```

Users I create with this playbook

```
- hosts: application
  tasks:

  - name: Check if authentication is enabled
    shell: 
      cmd: "/usr/bin/mongo -u admin -p {{ password.admin }} --authenticationDatabase admin --norc --quiet localhost:{{ ports.router }}"
      executable: /bin/bash
      stdin: exit 
    register: authenticate
    failed_when: false
    changed_when: false
    check_mode: no
    when: inventory_hostname_short == (groups['application'] | sort | first)

  - name: Create admin user
    shell: 
      cmd: "/usr/bin/mongo {{ (authenticate.rc == 0) | ternary('-u admin -p ' + password.admin + ' --authenticationDatabase admin', '') }} --norc --quiet localhost:{{ ports.router }}"
      executable: /bin/bash
      stdin: |
        const admin = db.getSiblingDB("admin")
        {% if authenticate.rc != 0 %}
        admin.createUser({ user: "admin", pwd: "{{ password.admin }}", roles: ["root"] })
        var _ = admin.auth("admin", "{{ password.admin }}")
        {% endif %}
        // Create more users if needed
    when: inventory_hostname_short == (groups['application'] | sort | first)
    register: ret_createUser
    changed_when: ret_createUser.stdout != ''

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ ret_createUser.stdout.split('\n') }}"
    when: not ansible_check_mode and inventory_hostname_short == (groups['application'] | sort | first) and ret_createUser.stdout != ''
```

Comment: Tried the one which you suggested.But getting error.Updated details in my question.Please have a look and give your suggesstions

Comment: finally it suceeded.Using youre suggesstion.But created admin user then i have tried

Comment: Please see my update. Printing `ret.stdout` should provide proper error message.